# Google OpenID login - how does x-has-session work?

Tags: openid, google-openid

I have a Google Chrome extension with an external user system (username/email/sessionId), that people can log into using their self-chosen credentials (over SSL). I would like to change this to using Google OpenID login like this:

1. User clicks "Log in via Google":
2. Extension performs a `checkid_immediate`* login request:

   - If `checkid_immediate` login fails:

     1. The extension will opens a new tab with the specified parameters for `checkid_setup`** login (and email fetch).
     2. User selects accounts and approves my service.
     3. On my return page I save the OpenID identity and email in my database.
     4. I close the tab via Javascript.
   - Else `checkid_immediate` is successfull and an OpenID identity is returned:

     1. I determine which user by looking for the OpenID identity in my database.
3. I log in the user and set up `sessionId` as usual.

As far as I have understood `x-has-session` will allow me to fetch the OpenID of the currently logged in user (if they have previously allowed my service to use their login), but the response is always `openid_mode=setup_needed`.

Using my own account for testing I am able to authorize using the new tab `checkid_setup` method and then get a successful response from the `checkid_immediate` XmlHttpRequest. **This is, however, only possible when I insert my obtained OpenID from Google in the `openid.claimed_id` and `openid.identity` parameters.**

The request is successfull regardless of the `openid.identity` and `openid.ui.mode` parameters.

Have I completely misunderstood what I can do with `x-has-session`?

If yes, is the only way to perform my `checkid_immediate` request from my extension (without opening it in a new tab) to do it via the OpenID identifier I obtained at the time of running the `checkid_setup` request?

---

*`checkid_immediate` request parameters (sent as a POST request using XMLHttpRequest):

```
var endpoint = "https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud";
var openIdParameters = {
  "openid.ns": "http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0",
  "openid.mode": "checkid_immediate",
  "openid.return_to": "http://example.com/googleAuth.php",
  "openid.realm": "http://example.com",
  "openid.claimed_id": "http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select",
  "openid.identity": "http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select",
  "openid.ns.ui": "http://specs.openid.net/extensions/ui/1.0",
  "openid.ui.mode": "x-has-session"
};
```

At the `openid.return_to` URL all I do is echo `json_encode($_REQUEST)` (only GET/POST vars, cookies not included) which is fetched as the response in my XmlHttpRequest.

---

*`checkid_setup` request parameters (opened in new tab):

```
var endpoint = "https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud";
var openIdParameters = {
  "openid.ns": "http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0",
  "openid.mode": "checkid_setup",
  "openid.return_to": "http://example.com/googleAuth.php",
  "openid.realm": "http://example.com",
  "openid.claimed_id": "http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select",
  "openid.identity": "http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select",
  "openid.ns.ax": "http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0",
  "openid.ax.mode": "fetch_request",
  "openid.ax.required": "email",
  "openid.ax.type.email": "http://axschema.org/contact/email"
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so I finally figured out why my test have been acting up weird (and why `x-has-session` seemed like it didn't do anything): If you are logged in with multipe accounts (which was the case for me) Google OpenID login works a bit differently.

Lets go through the differences (these results are obtained via my own testing, so they may not be 100% accurate - they are also assuming nothing else would triggers a `setup_needed` response from Google, such as switching `openid.realm`):

---

**1:** Immediate requests not specifying OpenID and not specifying `x-has-session`:

- **Not logged in:** Google specifies the parameter `openid_mode=setup_needed` in the response.
- **Single session:** If user has approved the service, Google specifies the parameter `openid_mode=id_res` otherwise `openid_mode=setup_needed` in the response.
- **Multiple sessions:** Google specifies the parameter `openid_mode=setup_needed` in the response regardless of having approved the service or not.

---

**2:** Immediate requests not specifying OpenID, but specifying `x-has-session`:

- **Not logged in:** Same as **1** (not logged in).
- **Single session:** If user has approved the service, Google specifies the parameter `openid_mode=id_res` and ignores `x-has-session` otherwise `openid_mode=setup_needed` and `openid_ext1_mode=x-has-session` in the response.
- **Multiple sessions:** Google specifies the parameter `openid_mode=setup_needed` in the response regardless of having approved the service or not.

---

**3:** Immediate requests specifying OpenID and not specifying `x-has-session`:

- **Not logged in:** Same as **1** (not logged in).
- **Single session:** Same as **1** (single session).
- **Multiple sessions:** Same as single session.

---

**4:** Immediate requests specifying OpenID and `x-has-session`:

- **Not logged in:** Same as **1** (not logged in).
- **Single session:** Same as **2** (single session).
- **Multiple sessions:** Same as single session.

---

In other words:

- If using single session, immediate mode using `x-has-session` can either tell you if a Google user is logged in or return a successful response if user has already approved the service **regardless of specifying their OpenID**.
- If using multiple sessions **and specifying the OpenID** the behavior is the same as single session.
- If using multiple sessions **without specifying the OpenID** immediate mode always returns a failure response and `x-has-session` is not applicable.